# Do you use (in?) Cubase

Tags: prepositions

Should I use the preposition "in," in the following context?

> Do you use (in?) Cubase?

I want to ask someone if he uses this software (of music).

Comment: You don't need to use any preposition, especially *in*. You can try *on* and that would work very well. When talking about software, we tend to use the preposition "on." *Do you work on Cubase?* and if you want to use the word "use" then you should not put any preposition after it. *Do you use Cubase?* That's my guess!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't have to use *'in'*. Using *"in"* changes the entire meaning of the sentence:

> Do you work in Cubase?

which means that you are talking about working in an actual place called Cubase.

Otherwise, you should just avoid *'in'* and frame the sentence as:

> Do you use Cubase?

Which means only one thing: "are you a person who uses the software Cubase?"

Comment: _Do you work **in** Cubase_ means you are talking about working in an actual place called Cubase. *Do you work in Cubase* is wrong considering what the OP is asking. Also, there is no space before a punctuation. :)